# is decoupling nestjs class validation from pipes a good idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

so when learning nest i got recommended by the docs on using dtos, pipes and class-validator for validating incoming payloads from requests

since then i was thinking about the possibility of having a service call from other places within the system other than http requests. i still had to validate the incoming payload, but since the validation logic is placed inside a pipe, the service was left not validated.

then i thought maybe creating another provider just for validating and decoupling the validation logic from the controller using the already installed by default class-validator and class-transformer packages

something like that for the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RandomEntityService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(RandomEntity) private randomEntityRepo: Repository<RandomEntity>,
    private randomEntityValidator: RandomEntityValidatorService,
  ) {}

  public async create(randomEntDto: RandomEntityCreateDto) {
    try {
      await this.randomEntityValidator.createValidation(randomEntDto);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new BadRequestException(err.message);
    }

    return this.randomEntityRepo.save(this.randomEntityRepo.create(randomEntDto));
  }

}
```

and something like that for the validator:

```
@Injectable()
export class RandomEntityValidatorService {

  public async createValidation(plainObject: Partial<RandomEntityCreateDto>) {
    const instance = plainToInstance(RandomEntityCreateDto, plainObject);

    const err = await validate(instance);

    if (err.length) {
      console.log(
        err.reduce((acc, e) => {
          acc.push(e.constraints);
          return acc;
        }, []),
      );
      throw new Error(err.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

not sure yet about error handling because it would have to be treated accordingly to whom called it i guess? but that is for tomorrow.

i mean, that way could i safely assume that calling the entity creation method from any other places would work and therefore save the pipe for other kinds of "http domain" logic? and that technically i am actually bringing business logic closer from outside providers to actual modules/providers?

never seen implemented that way but it may actually work and it makes some sense in my head.

and i kinda got stuck with the dto as data transfer object as a valid terminology for this "pattern" since the calling argument could actually be a dto from http or a plain object from let's say a cron routine. not sure about that either.

is this approach valid considering good practices and node modularization patterns?

Comment: Usually when you create the objects yourself, they are already validated (you create them properly or from database, therefore you dont need to revalidate them).  When you receive the objects from 3-rd party actors (for example users) there is a need for validation of the data so you use the pipeline to do so. 

As for the service, good idea - but only if you use generic service, which you give class object already (so DTO) and then execute validation on it. You also can think of 2 ways of returning the validation status: Boolean and/or Errors/undefined.

Comment: Eihter way, i would use EventEmitter2 for that service to communicate instead of importing it into every place, which could also allow of some more complex validations (or multiple validations), or other things you might think of

Comment: @Seti thanks for the comment.
i hardcoded the validation for simplifying the example but maybe doing it a bit more generic is really the most appropriate. also, never heard about EE2 eheh i just used the standard one, will check it out. and when you say about using it for the service, you mean the validation or the creation one? i was under the impression that DI would "take care" of the imports somehow

Comment: EE2 is just never better version, very compatible with old - just better wrote + ts.

And exactly - i use my own small service for type validation for my developers - nothing more